# Help converting a string date to a DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the Ajax control toolkit calendar extender on a textbox with a submit button. Simple.

The debugger shows that the text is properly being transferred to calling method, but this line of conversion code converts textbox text to 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM. The text box date is this: 4/15/2011

```
DateTime txtMyDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, what do you want is a DateTime value that holds a date only ?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) method:

```
DateTime txtMyDate = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text);
```

As mentioned you can also use [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) using a similar syntax as shown:

```
DateTime txtMyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, 
                                         [string format], 
                                         [IFormatProvider provider]);
```

**Parse vs ParseExact:**

**Parse()** - assumes the data is valid and does its best to fit it into the type, forcing things that seem vaguely ridiculous when a developer has a chance to invoke common sense.

**ParseExact()** - only allows the exact format specified and will throw on any variation.

[Source on Parse vs ParseExact](http://www.siao2.com/2005/11/17/492197.aspx)

Comment: Weirdly, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) says that `Convert.ToDateTime(string)` actually calls `DateTime.Parse()`, so I'm kinda curious as to why calling `DateTime.Parse()` directly would work if `Convert.ToDateTime()` didn't.

Comment: You are still receiving 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM as your DateTime? If that is occurring then it is probably an issue with the data not being passed in properly or a value isn't being set.

Comment: yes it was my fault. As both this answer and Matt Greer's answer is correct, I am choosing this one as it explains the difference between `Parse` and `ParseExact`.

Comment: Will any of this work without `using System.Globalization;` namespace? ;)

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to convert text to a DateTime, try this one:

```
DateTime txtMyDate = 
  DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Edit: forgot the culture info argument

Comment: This wants an IFormatProvider for its third argument.

Comment: @Nick - yeah I realized I was missing it, edited it in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to extract your date value from a formated date string:

```
DateTime dateValue = 
   DateTime.ParseExact(stringDateValue, "M/d/yyyy", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DateTime instance = DateTime.Parse( txtDate.Text ) ;
```

which is [somewhat] flexible about what it will accept. Alternatively, `DateTime.ParseExact()` will give you move control over the conversion.